# How to insert paragraph tags on newlines without tag overlapping?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string with some HTML markup, but without any paragraphs. I want to replace newlines with paragraph tags, but if I do it "the dumb way":

```
html.gsub!(/\s*\n+\s*/, '</p><p>')
html = '<p>' + html + '</p>'
```

, then I will get markup overlapping:

```
This is text. <b>Bold text.\n
Still bold,</b> now plain.
```

becomes:

```
<p>This is text. <b>Bold text.</p><p>Still bold,</b> now plain.</p>
```

I know that HTML5 allows overlapping tags, but it is still very-very ugly. I want to get something like this:

```
<p>This is text. <b>Bold text.</b></p><p><b>Still bold,</b> now plain.</p>
```

How can I fix this problem?

UPD. `<br/>` is not what I need - I intend to use Kramdown with custom parser to generate Markdown from this string, and in the string I need open and closing tag for each paragraph.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2651076

Comment: Thank you, but I do not intend to parse HTML by Regex - in fact, I explicitly called it "a dumb way" =-)

Answer (score 0):

Insert HTML `<br>` tags. They are well-defined as standalone tags that don't have paired end tags. If XHTML were still a thing, they would be `<br/>` tags.

Comment: Sorry, but for further processing I need paired tags.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a `<br>` tag you can insert a single line break. It also has no end tag, so no need to try and close it.

[W3Schools - < br > Tag](https://codepen.io/aeveritt84/pen/wXeYMv)

## UPDATED:

If you need paired tags you could create a line break using CSS.

## **HTML**

```
<p class="break">
  Break right after this and
  <span>before this</span>
</p>
```

## **CSS**

```
p.break {
  span {
    display: table;
  }
}
```

As shown here on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/aeveritt84/pen/wXeYMv).

Comment: Sorry, but for further processing I need paired tags.